# Typescript not converting decimals properly

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class that I need an actual decimal field

```
export myclass {
deposit: number;
}
```

however when i convert my web api class to this typescript class my decimal amounts that should look like this
1.10 look like this 1.1 when the object is converted.

I need that zero to stay put. How can I do this in typescript?

Answer (score 3):

A `number` type is always going to remove trailing zeroes in the decimals place. To have `1.10` you would need to represent it as a string.

You can use `toFixed` to specify the number of decimal places you want, but the output is a string.

```js
const num = 1.10;

console.log(num);
console.log(num.toFixed(2));
```